# How the same namespace works in a single solution with different projects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, namespaces

I have a MVC application(solution) having multiple projects in it. That is DaL, Utility, workflow etc...

In Dal, There is one namespace as " xyz.home.smart.Dal" In the namespace there is a Public partial "SqlEngine" class.

The same SqlEngine class(only class,No Dal reference; having same namespace) is included in the workflow project.

I have modified the "SqlEngine" Class in workflow and upon building I'm getting the Workflow DLL(work fine). However, along with this the other projects DLL are also building (note- I have not modified the "SqlEngine" in other projects).

How the DLLs are getting modified in other projects? Is it that, this is happening because of same namespace?

Comment: Have a look at the project dependencies in your solution. When any project is rebuilt, then all projects that have it as a dependency must be rebuilt. Then any projects that have *those* as a dependency, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespace changes are not relevant to other projects.

Two likely causes for those builds:

- Either you are doing "Build all".
- Or these other projects depend on DaL (have a reference to it), so each time DaL is built they have to be built to make sure they aren't broken by changes in DaL.

Comment: 1st of all, the "namespace" is same, it's not changed from project to project. Yes, I did build the entire solution.i do not see DAL reference to it.